# Passing additional parameters to Google Analytics using URL link-tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I am setting up email marketing tracking within Google Analytics and would like to pass on an additional custom parameter to capture the subject of the email. ex: http://www.google.com/?utm_source=targeted_email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=sale&subject=Sale

I would rather not use any of the basic parameters as they are all being used within GA for other campaigns and it would muck up my existing analytics quite a bit.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GA has custom variables you can use to report values, yes. But what do you mean by "basic parameters?" is that what you are talking about, as far as "basic parameters" or are you referring to the other utm_xxx vars?  if you are not wanting to use custom variables, then no, there really isn't an alternative.

But the [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) are fairly robust..perhaps it is a question of categorizing them properly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!


By custom variables I mean something outside of the five values the GA normally has (utm_source, utm_medium, utm_term, utm_content, utm_campaign).


What I am asking for is something outside of those five.

Comment: okay then yes, GA provides custom variables you can use for passing arbitrary values. I edited my post to linkify "custom variables", pointing to instructions on how to implement them.

Comment: I'm wondering how I can use them within purely a URL based link tagging system (as I can't use other code within an email).

I looked through that page prior to posting this question and it seemed to only refer to javascript.

Comment: Okay yeah, unfortunately GA does not provide url-only equivalents to custom variables.  What you *can* do is make up your own url variables and then write some code to look for those urls and pop the custom variables with the url params you made.  But that still involves doing some page coding.

Comment: Thanks! (Filler text for char count)